# How to put 32-bit signed integer into higher 32 bits of 64-bit unsigned integer?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

Example:

```
qint32 si32 = -1; // that gives us 0xFFFFFFFF
quint64 ui64 = si32; // that gives us 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, that is expected
```

Desired result:

```
0xFFFFFFFF00000000
```

When I'm trying to shift bits on si32 like this

```
quint64 ui64 = si32 << 32;
```

compiler warns me about bit-shifting overflow.

That should be an easy task, but I can't figure out how to do that.
That is a unix C++ code (using QT, but that doesn't matter, plain unix C++ code will do).

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: _"plain unix C++ code will do"_ So why not posting a [MCVE] without the _irrelevant_ stuff?

Comment: What does `quint64 ui64 = ((quint64)si32) << 32;` do? Does it give the error still?

Comment: i guess you would have to first use a `quint64` before shifting. If you shift a `qint32` by 32 there is nothing left anymore. `quint64 temp = si32; temp << 32` I would expect to work

Comment: How? `ui64 = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000`.

Comment: I think it's pretty easy to write `unsigned int` instead of "quin32", but I just coy-pasted, Still anyone can understand my example. And there is a minimal example, so why down vote?

Comment: @rightaway717 Everyone researching for a similar problem and being pointed to your question will _stumble_ over these Qt specific data types. If you're asking for Qt, why not use the existing [tag:qt] tag beforehand?

Comment: @rightaway717: Also, the basic idea is that anyone wanting to reproduce your results should not be required to do more than copy, save, compile, run. That means an example should be *compilable* if at all possible, on as many targets as possible. Swapping the Qt-specific types for standard ones and adding the necessary `int main()` boilerplate saves *everyone* some time -- except you of course, but then again you want the answer, and it makes sure you didn't overlook something and your example is *actually* valid code. You could've detected your question is not about Qt at all, for example.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree with you, that compilable example is a good thing, though I believe that some examples don't need to be compilable, as there are things that are more mathematical, for instance, or computer science, than code itself. So I believe my question is like such. I did't add `qt` tag, that was someone else.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because it is not a QT question, thus no `qt` tag, for other people to find it easier. If you don't like the example, feel free to edit it, ask me edit it, etc, but down voting  it is another thing. It's like you are having a bad mood and go over questions just to down vote  them

Comment: @rightaway717: And again you are wasting everybody's time.

Comment: @rightaway717 The question and all the answers actually **are Qt specific**. None of the standard integer types was mentioned here. As I said before it would be very confusing for future research. You should have left that [tag:qt] tag there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Edited it, now it's Qt-free, and a MCVE, and *perhaps* the OP will learn something in the process. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar, The answer still uses QT types though. :)

Comment: @DevSolar That wasn't the right action. 1. It's a radical change. 2. It invalidates the accepted answer. Instead of editing the question you should have written an answer, leaving out the Qt specific stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning has to do with the size of `si32` itself. Basically the sequence of steps looks like this:

1. Take `si32` (which is a 32bit value)
2. Shift that value by 32bits (i.e. shift a 32bit value by 32 bits)
3. Assign it to `ui64`.

To fix that, you can first cast `si32` to the proper 64bit type, before shifting it by 32 bits so the bit shifting will operate on 64bit values:

```
quint64 ui64 = ((quint64) si32) << 32;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I actually tried it, but I must have missed something, as I had got a wrong result.

Comment: @rightaway717, an important part is, that you cast it to an unsigned type. Otherwise the compiler may sign extend the value, which will give wrong results. In your given example this wouldn't be noticable , but if you try a bit pattern with the highest bit set, you will see the effect.

Comment: @Devolus So if I got you correctly, I must not cast to signed type like this, because it's not clear if highest bit (sign bit) will be set or not?

Comment: A signed value has to be assumed that the bit is set, and that is why the compiler can use an instruction to extend the sign. So to avoid unexpected results during the move you have to cast to unsigned. Always.